# Django Rest Framework, how can I delete the email field in the rest_auth authentication?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django-users, django-rest-auth

I solved my previous problems with the following tutorial
https://wsvincent.com/django-rest-framework-user-authentication-tutorial/

My problem now is that by default, the login asks for the fields "useraname", "email" and "password"

Is there a way I can skip the verification by email?

I tried adding in my settings.py:

```
ACCOUNT_EMAIL_REQUIRED = False
```

And it works, but the django User has to have an email (and i only create my Users with username and password), it works because I tried with my superuser, who has an email, but what about the Django users who created them with an empty email?

code where i register:

```
class Registrar(mixins.CreateModelMixin, viewsets.GenericViewSet):

        serializer_class = UsuarioSerializer

        def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
            #  Creando un nuevo usuario
            username = request.POST.get('user.username')
            password = request.POST.get('user.password')
            es_tecnico = False
            print(username)

            user = User.objects.create_user(username, password)
            user.save() #i want to use this django user to login, and i created it without email

            token = Token.objects.create(user=user)

            usuario = Usuario.objects.create(user = user, es_tecnico = es_tecnico)
            usuario.save()

            return Response({'detail': 'El usuario fue creado con el token: ' + token.key})



My custom user "Usuario":
    class Usuario(models.Model):
        user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
        es_tecnico = models.BooleanField(name = 'es_tecnico', default = False)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `AbstractUser`, and create a new Authentication User Model.
[Details](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/auth/customizing/)

Comment: i added code to my question, i create the django without email, my custom user is linket to that user but i need the django user for login, and what i undestands (because my superuser work) its not necesary to write it, but its necesary to have it (if i leave the field clean when i login with my superuser, it works, because it asks for a email when created)

Comment: Can you create new model with your created app. For example;
```
#in your app models.py
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser

class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
    ex_tecnico = models.BooleanField(name='es_tecnico', default=False)
#in your app forms.py
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from yourapp.models import CustomUser

class CustomSignupForm(UserCreationForm):
    class Meta(UserCreationForm.Meta):
        model = CustomUser
        Fields= ('username, 'name', 'ex_tecnico',) #...
    def save(self, commit=False):
        ...
````